# Detect and Count vehicle and people in opencv python

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, video-processing, image-recognition, roi

I am new to OpenCV and have got a project to detect and count the number of vehicles and people in a video taken from a still camera. From Google, I found out that background subtractor helps but have some queries though:

1. What is the use of background subtractor if I can detect (but could not count) vehicles and humans from the original video? Background subtractor makes the original video into a binary video.
2. Detection in the original video is inconsistent. If my Region of Interest (ROI) is a line then there is hardly any count. On the other hand, if my ROI is a rectangle then one vehicle gets count many times.
3. How to count the vehicles and people in a time frame? For eg.: No. of people (or vehicle) per minute. Store the number and count again after a minute. And the process continues.

Thank You.

Comment: Can you attach sample consecutive input frames

Comment: Couly you please split that up into several questions?

Comment: 1) For vehicle and human detections, OpenCV provides haar cascade in .xml to train the algorithm and I can detect using the coordinates of the vehicles in the sample video. So, what is the use of background subtractor then? 2) There is multiple counting of the same vehicle. For eg. If a car gets tracked in 3 consecutive frames, the count increases by 3 instead of 1. The car must be tracked till the end but counting (increment by 1 only) is to be done only when the car crosses the line of intersection. 3) I need to count the no of people and no of vehicles per min the same video. @JensBaitinger

Comment: Sorry, I do not know how to take the snapshots of the consecutive frames. @ZdaR

Comment: @MananBothra 
Did you find any  solution  of this problem 
"If  Region of Interest (ROI) is a line then there is hardly any count. ' ?